# Google Sheets: shared 'Make a Copy' link but still requesting access to master copy

Tags: google-sheets, sharing, permissions

I have been sharing spreadsheet templates on Google Sheets via links which instruct the users to make a copy, so they are able to fully access and edit their own version (by changing 'edit' to 'copy' in the sharing URL) - example below

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sWB-FBUXW6rW4NCqdH5SRA8UfgUgc0A9K_zsjFIaBh8/copy?usp=sharing

This works 95% of the time, but sometimes I still receive requests to access the master spreadsheet from people with the 'make a copy' link and I don't know how/why this is, they should not have the option to access the master spreadsheet and it should not be available to them (unless they know to change the URL back which seems unlikely).

If anyone please has a solution or even an explanation I would be really grateful!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think they changed the link ... it's very easy after all!